# «Он часто слышал это слово(,) техника(,) и решительно не понимал...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Из «Анны Карениной». Герои посещают студию художника Михайлова.

> — Да, удивительное мастерство! — сказал Вронский. — Как эти фигуры на заднем плане выделяются! Вот техника, — сказал он, обращаясь к Голенищеву и этим намекая на бывший между ними разговор о том, что Вронский отчаивался приобрести эту технику.
> — Да, да, удивительно! — подтвердили Голенищев и Анна. Несмотря на возбужденное состояние, в котором он находился, замечание о технике больно заскребло на сердце Михайлова, и он, сердито посмотрев на Вронского, вдруг насупился. Он часто слышал **это слово *техника*** и решительно не понимал, что такое под этим разумели. Он знал, что под этим словом разумели механическую способность писать и рисовать, совершенно независимую от содержания.

Можно ли поставить запятые вокруг слова «техника»? Я думаю, его можно считать уточнением к «это слово». Почему автор не поставил запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Его нельзя считать уточнением из-за указательного местоимения *это.* Вместе с ним словосочетание неразрывно. Интонация совсем не та, что при уточнении. Передать тот смысл, что вы имели в виду, можно, поставив в скобки *технику,* однако авторское прочтение и, соответственно, пунктуация мне видятся гораздо более естественными.

Обычно уточнение иначе характеризует то, что уточняют, и произнести всё вместе не получается без маленьких пауз, здесь же мы видим простое словосочетание, в котором *техника* поясняет *слово.* Уберите слово *это* — смысл останется тем же, но обособить *технику,* посчитав уточнением, уже никак не получится.